# matlab character distribution from text file

Tags: matlab, probability

I am trying to plot the distribution of the text file, however i found that I should include the numbers 0-9 and _ -  also to the below codes

```
 f = fopen('c:\nouns.txt');
ns = textscan(f, '%s');
fclose(f);
%// Convert everything to chars
letters_char = reshape(char(ns{:}),[],1);

%// Get the case-insensitive count of each letter 
count_lettters = sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,97:122),1) + ...
    sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,65:90),1)

plot(count_lettters./sum(count_lettters))
bar(count_lettters./sum(count_lettters))
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',cellstr(char(97:122)'),'XTick',1:26)
```

this will compute and plot the distribution of letters from a-z 
I want to include a-z and 0-9 and - and _ 
any suggests ?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example and be more precise on the issue you encounter.

Comment: is  this enough or you need more details ?>

Comment: Try running just the section you provided.. I guess at least a definition of `@eq` is still missing.

Comment: it is updated now .....and this works on my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
f = fopen(path_to_text_file);
ns = textscan(f, '%s');
fclose(f);

%// Convert everything to chars
letters_char = reshape(char(ns{:}),[],1);

%// Get the case-insensitive count of each letter 
count_lettters = sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,97:122),1) + ...
    sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,65:90),1);

count_numbers = sum(bsxfun(@eq,letters_char,48:57),1)

underscore_c = sum(letters_char=='_')
hyphen_c = sum(letters_char=='-')

counts = [underscore_c hyphen_c count_numbers count_lettters]

xtickstr = ['_'; '-'; cellstr(num2str([0:9]')) ; cellstr(char(97:122)')]
bar(counts./sum(counts))
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',xtickstr,'XTick',1:numel(xtickstr))

xlabel('ASCII Characters')
ylabel('Probability Distribution')
```

**Output plot for a typical text file**

[image]